# Deploy .net winforms application in client machine plus database sql server 2005?

Tags: .net, sql-server, deployment, installation

i have .net 3.5 application developed and this application use sql server 2005 database so i want to make easy deployment for this  application in simple way that all users can install it so i will add deployment project the problem is there is 3 prerequisites as follow 
 1 - .net framework 2.0 its sql server prerequisite
 2 -.net framework  3.5  my app use it  ( i am asking also if i put target .net in my  project when building to .net 2.0 this will be not needed ?? ) 
 3 - sql express 2005

if i add all of them as prerequisites and install from the same location my app installed then the problem is just 32 bit from .net 2.0 and sql server will be added what if client have 64 bit os want to install it ???

with respect

thanks in advance

Comment: Please test your setup.exe on a x64 machine and tell whar happens...

Comment: Will you send sql express for 64 bits? I don't even remember if that exists... if not just target your app x86 and will work on 32 bits. what are you really asking here?

Comment: i am asking for is there any easy way to make application work in x86 and x64 with single setup file also does .net framework 2.0 32 bit that sql server 2005 express edition requiere work in 64 bit i have problem on my clients they say the deployment is too hard you know that developer machine contain all packages that applications requiere to work so clients machine not have .net framework 2.0 this is big problem can i package sql server and .net framework in silent installer ?? with my application

Comment: @ReSharper If you need to target two types of PC, you will need to packages, one for 32 and one for 64. You can package everything you need on the msi (or at least send everything on the same cd/dvd/zip file).

Comment: Thank you @gbianchi also i have question does windows xp sp2 and wndows 7  have  embeded .net framework 2.0 ? or not ?? 

with respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the packages you need to the msi file. or deploy them in the same folder as the package.
To target two enviroments, you need to differents exes and two differents packages.
Win 7 has the framework 2.0. I can't be sure about XP (I think so, but just in case, just send it. you can't be never sure about it).

Comment: Thank you @gbianchi i will build it twice to X86 and X64 then will make msi and i will add .net as prerequisites  

with respect